# Error Using NetMeasurements (assessing neural network performance)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to assess how well a neural network regression model performs on test data. To do this I have used NetMeasurements command.

```
net1 = NetChain[{LinearLayer[200], ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid], 
LinearLayer[200], ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid], LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> 40, 
"Output" -> "Scalar"]   

trainednet1 = NetTrain[net1, traindata, All, ValidationSet -> validationdata, 
BatchSize -> Automatic, LossFunction -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[], Method -> "SGD"] 

NetMeasurements[net1, testdata, "Output"]
```

When I do this, I get the following error message

[image: NetMeasurements::nninit]

What could the issue possibly be?

I have wondered if "net1" should be replaced by "trainednet1" in the argument of NetMeasurements. But, then I get another error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NetTrain in your example has All as an argument, so it results in a NetTrainResultsObject instead of a neural network. Use trainednet1["TrainedNet"] instead of just trainednet1 to refer to the neural network.

Also, for NetMeasurements, you have to specify that "Output" is a port of the network. Use NetPort["Output"] instead of just "Output".

```
NetMeasurements[trainednet1["TrainedNet"], testdata, NetPort["Output"]]
```

Comment: What you said about the trained net is very helpful. If I also swap the Output measurement to just “RSquared” then it works fine now. However, if I keep Output and use NetPort as you say then I still get an error but it’s about specifying the loss port of the net using LossFunction???

Comment: testdata should be a list of inputs for the neural network, instead of a list of rules (input -> output). With that, NetMeasurements gives you the mean of the outputs given the inputs.

Nevertheless, "RSquared" is more likely to be what you are looking for.

Comment: You can check and see The wolfram documentation says the data should take the input->output form in the details section of NetMeasurents.

Comment: I was hoping to calculate the mean error between the predicted and actual outputs.

Comment: Use "MeanDeviation" instead of "RSquared".